# Microsoft Excel: Using "INT" Function With Time Format

Tags: excel

Just a quick question here.

Why does performing the INT function on a cell formatted as a time return a "0", but multiplying the INT function of a time-formatted cell by some number gives you a value[image]?  I've attached a picture for reference.  If I were to instead do "=INT((A2)*1440)" I get a value of 780.

[image]

Comment: Check your parentheses...

Comment: The value of A2 is obviously less than 1, and INT function rounds down...

Comment: @musefan but the value of A2 is 13:00.  I guess I'm confused as to how that's less than one.  Can you help me understand that?

Comment: Is it because it's treating 13:00 as a fraction of a day, e.g., (13/24)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you were expecting the result to be, unless perhaps your parentheses are off, i.e. `=INT((A2)*1440)` is not the same as `INT(A2)*1440`.

1:00:00 PM is equivalent to about 0.54. Times are fractions of 1, one day = 1, so 1:00:00 PM = 13/24 ≈ 0.54.

`INT(13/24*1440)` gives you 780.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense.  I think what I didn't know is that Excel treats time-formatted cells as a fraction of a day.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, if one day is one then by definition hours are fractions of 1. Change the cell format to number to see the actual numeric value.